# Parse REST Json replay

Tags: views, 8

I  create a views with `REST export` display, result are serialized with `Json`,

In my formBuild method  I want to parse JSON and Convert it to array and use it in select option

```
    $host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()
        ->get($host.'/get/slider' );

    $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    kint($json_string);
```

I see [Symfony serialize class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) and find `Deserialize` method with this example

```
 $person = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Person', 'xml');
```

According to this,I guess maybe I should something like

```
     $results = $serializer->deserialize($json_string, '???', 'josn');
```

but what I should write in second param(???)? 
I try

```
    $serialize = new Serializer\Serializer();
    $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
  $entity = $serialize->deserialize($json_string, '\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::class', 'json')  ;
```

but face me with error `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Deserialization for the format json is not supported in Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer->deserialize()`.

And if you have better solution  tell me 
**How Can I deserilized views REST results?**

**update**
Also,I tried

```
    $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
    $deserialized = $serializer->deserialize($json_string, \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::class, 'json');
```

but `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: A string must be provided as a bundle value. in Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer->denormalize()`

Comment: It might not be the only problem, but `'\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::class'` isn't right...that would either be `'\Drupal\node\Entity\Node'` or `\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::class` (no quotes). The latter being preferred

Comment: @Clive I tried but the same, I think  I choose bad method to parse json to array in Drupal 8, in drupal 7 it was simple just `json_decode` .

Comment: You can still use that (or `Json::decode` which is in D8), but that will leave you with an associative array like it would in D7. The idea of the serializer is to map the json straight back onto a classed object which is much better to work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has a service for serialisation, pre-configured with the normalisers and encoders you need. The error you currently have is because you're not setting up the instance of the serialiser with the `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder`, but you'll also need, for example, the `Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\ConfigEntityNormalizer` normaliser.

This code works well for me:

```
$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load(1);

$output = $serializer->serialize($node, 'json');
$deserialized_node = $serializer->deserialize($output, \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::class, 'json');
```

As always, inject the services if possible.

Comment: tnx dear Clive for attention, I try your solution , but `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: A string must be provided as a bundle value. in Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\EntityNormalizer->denormalize()` , take a look on my question again( I update it with your suggest). how I use normalize ?

Comment: What is you suggest Clive? Did you Think the @David Mcsmith solution is better? it work but I'm not sure it's good way.

Answer (score 1):

Try `json_decode`,
first  `use Drupal\Core\Serializer;`

then in your code use

```
 $json_string = $response->getBody()->getContents();  
 $res =json_decode($json_string);
```

Comment: your solution worked, but I am not sure it is the best way,?